# How can I use built-in trigonometric funtions in Z3 Python?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I would like to do something like: `Exists y. 0<=cos(y)<=1.`, which could return a model e.g., `y:=50`. Is this possible in Z3?

I know SMT solvers overall are problematic for non-linear/trascendental operations [1], and indeed have not been implemented for a while [2,3]. However, it looks like at least for  trigonometric functions there is some support [4,5] and, moreover, it looks like it is already built-in, like in the function `cos` of [6].

Thus, I tried the following in Z3-PY:

```
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
solver = Solver()
solver.add(Exists([x],cos(x)<1))
solver.check()
model = solver.model()
```

... but looks like `cos` is not recognized. Do you know how can I use this? I have some alternative methods in mind that do no use Z3, but I want to explore this possibility in order to keep everything implemented in the same block.

[1] [SMT solvers for real closed fields (e.g., trascendentals and infinitesimals) in practise? Z3, MetiTarski, dReal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159065/smt-solvers-for-real-closed-fields-e-g-trascendentals-and-infinitesimals-in)

[2] [Can Z3 handle sinusoidal and exponential functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148707/can-z3-handle-sinusoidal-and-exponential-functions)

[3] [Z3 support for nonlinear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064822/z3-support-for-nonlinear-arithmetic)

[4] https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/680

[5] [Support of trigonometric functions ( e.g.: cos, tan) in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433210/support-of-trigonometric-functions-e-g-cos-tan-in-z3)

[6] [Undocumented trigonometric functions in Z3 reparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711933/undocumented-trigonometric-functions-in-z3-reparable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trigonometric functions in z3 if you stick to the SMTLib interface:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-fun x () Real)
(assert (< (cos x) 1.0))
(check-sat)
```

alas, this doesn't get you far. For the above, z3 says:

```
unknown
```

and this'll be the case for most problems using trigonometric functions. Support for them is extremely lightweight: They are more or less treated as uninterpreted functions with some axioms (like `sin^2 + cos^2 = 1`), which can handle some simple queries but not much.

It doesn't look like you can access these from the Python API. Not because it can't be done, but probably no-one bothered since the support is rather weak anyhow. (i.e., you can define them yourself on the Python side as uninterpreted functions with several axioms, and you'd pretty much match what z3 SMTLib support for them there is.)

If you're interested in trigonometric functions and automated theorem proving, your best bet is MetiTarski ([https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Elp15/papers/Arith/)). If you want something a bit more push-button and are happy with delta-satisfiability, then dReal is another tool you should look at: https://dreal.github.io.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, for me "they are more or less treated as uninterpreted functions with some axioms" was very clarifying. As for the delta-satisfiability alternative, do you know if there is some quantified-version of it? For instance, instead of performing the query `Exists y. 0<=cos(y)<=1` (with a certain precision), perform the query `ForAll y. 0<=cos(y)<=1`.

Comment: I don’t think `dReal` supports quantifiers, you might want to ask at their github site to double check. If you want to reason about trigonometric functions and quantifiers together, I think proper theorem provers are your only option for the time being. I’d start with MetiTarski.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, MetiTarski is not push-button, right?

Comment: Correct. None of the theorem provers are, but support for automation has been increasing. You might also want to check out Lean, which has a huge repertoire of mathematical theories.

Comment: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib-overview.html has a very nice summary of what Lean folks have been diligently building over the last decade or so.

Comment: Some more details: The level of support you get in z3 for trigonometric functions only allow it to answer `unsat` or `unknown`. That is, when trigonometric functions are involved, the solver will never say `sat`. Why? Because the solver does not have a decision procedure for such terms. It can only soundly conclude `unsat`, but if it internally comes up with `sat`, the model might be bogus due to the use of uninterpreted functions. This is why they are less than useful. (But still sound.)

Comment: If you want to stick to z3, another approach could be to use Taylor-expansion to an acceptable degree (assuming you're OK with approximations), and hope that the non-linear terms that arise will be solvable by the NRA solver. This can pay off for scientific applications where approximate results are OK; but not for full mathematical accuracy. Hard to opine any further without knowing exactly what your use case is.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information, again! As for the `sat/unsat` thing you mentioned, it makes total sense to me that only `unsat` can be soundly concluded; indeed, in delta-satisfiability we can conclude `unsat` (just like in your case) but also `delta-sa`t (but never `sat`), so I think both ideas converge. As for the last comment, it is also very interesting. I just made a new question to address it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206236/taylor-expansion-trigonometric-functions-in-z3-python